# How to handle Date in format Like "Wednesday-September 7-2011"

Tags: r

I am trying to get Date column from an excel data. The format of date in excel is like **`Wednesday-September 7-2011`**.

How do I handle dates in such format? I've read the documentation on Date and cannot find any method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
as.Date("Wednesday-September 7-2011", "%A-%B %d-%Y")
 # [1] "2011-09-07"
```

[image]

https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

Comment: It's just reading the Date, not the Day!
Is there any way I can read the day as well?

Comment: It's reading all four pieces (day name, month, day number, year). I think you're confusing how the date is stored with how it's displayed. Try this: `mydate <- as.Date("Wednesday-September 7-2011", "%A-%B %d-%Y")` and then run `format(mydate, "%Y-%m-%d %A")`

Answer (score 1):

If all your dates follow the same format, then I 'd suggest to remove the day and parse the rest, i.e.

```
x <- 'Wednesday - September 7 - 2011'
y <- paste(strsplit(x, ' - ')[[1]][-1], collapse = ' ')
#which gives [1] "September 7 2011"

as.POSIXct(y, format = '%B %d %Y')
#[1] "2011-09-07 EEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably strip out the weekday name and then parse the rest of the date. For example:

```
x <- "Wednesday-September 7-2011"
pos <- regexpr("-", x)
y<- (substr(x,pos+1,nchar(x)))
z<- parse_date(y, format = "%B %d-%Y")
```